# what are the steps to implements annotations in struts framework?

Tags: struts2

i'm using struts with struts.xml configuration. but have to know the annotation for zero configuration struts implementation. i complete all legacy steps to use annotations. but im unable to call my action annoation @Action(value=/"Action_method"). it throws the exception

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name Action_method. - [unkn
own location]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy
.java:178)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.j
ava:61)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(St
rutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(D
efaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.jav
a:478)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(Exec
uteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:45
4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


    enter code here<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping></web-app>
```

Comment: Not enough info. Where did you put that annotation? Which plugins are you using? What is your app conf looks like?

Comment: It's a warning, if you don't like to see turn `devMode` off.

Comment: i have use my annotation in my action class. and my web.xml is looks like this.

Comment: <filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
   </filter-class>
   <init-param>
         <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping></web-app>

Comment: and im using all formal struts2 plugins in my struts library.